# Не справился с управлением транспортным средством/транспортного средства?

Tags: грамматика

What way is correct here?

> ... водитель не справился с управлением транспортным средством

or

> ... водитель не справился с управлением транспортного средства

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what do you mean.

*Управление* may mean either

- Interface for controlling a device.
- Process of controlling a device.

When you are playing a computer game you can say:

- У этой игры сложное управление.
- Управление этой игры рассчитано на дураков.

But you cannot say "управление этой игрой рассчитано на дураков". Why? Because even though the game has control interface, it is not the game which you control, but some objects inside the game (unless you are a jury). But when referring a starship in this game you can say

- "У звездолета в этой игре сложное управление"
- "Управление звездолёта в этой игре рассчитано на дураков".

  (when referring to the interface)
- "Управление зведолетом закончилось, когда я пристыковался к орбитальной станции"
- "Управление звездолётом затянулось надолго"

  (when referring to the process)

Since an automobile both has a control interface and can be controlled, the both can be used but with different meaning.

- Он не разобрался с управлением этого автомобиля

(he did not understand the interface)

This phrase can refer to a class of automobiles:

- Он не разобрался с управлением этой модели автомобилей

But when referring to the process,

- Управление автомобилем - не простое дело

you cannot use Genitive case.

=======

Just some examples:

- Он не разобрался с управлением этой модели автомобилей

He did not understand the control interface of this model

- Он не разобрался с управлением этой моделью автомобилей

He being a marketing specialist (brand-manager) failed to position this model on the market

- Он не справился с управлением автомобиля

He failed to properly use the automobile control interface (which led to a catastrophe).

- Он не справился с управлением автомобилем

He failed the task to control the automobile (which led to a failed exam in the automobile school for the subject "управление автомобилем").

Comment: Yes, I think you are right - it really depends on whether a process is meant by the speaker, in which case the Instrumental case should be used, or a control panel (device, interface, etc.), in which case Genitive case must be used. Since there are two equal possibilities here, we can't say that using Genitive case in this phrase is grammatically incorrect. It will be absolutely correct if the speaker means a device, and it will be incorrect if he means a process.

Comment: @Even more: using Genitive is mandatory in this case, unless you mean that the person failed *the task or order or assignment to control the vehicle*.

Comment: Compare: "Он не справился с вчерашним управлением космической станцией, хотя у него был приказ управлять ей до сближения с планетой." vs. "Он не справился с управлением космической станции - оно оказалось рассчитано на марсиан."

Comment: @brilliant a quick check is to test whether you can substitute "система управления" or "сеанс управления" in place of "управление".

Comment: @brilliant When speaking about an accident, one can say "от не справился с системой управления автомобиля и врезался в столб", but cannot say "он не справился с сеансом управления автомобилем и врезался в столб".

Comment: +1 for clear expression of what I failed to explain. By the way we can use another meaning of `управление`: `организация, учреждение` to describe Kafkaesque situation where protagonist (`водитель`) failed to overcome (`не справился`) with evil organization (`Управление Транспортным Средством (УТС)`)

Answer (score 4):

While you may encounter both versions in conversations, the correct way is

> ... водитель не справился с управлением транспортным средством

In this case, you use the instrumental case: *управление [чем] транспортным средством*.

As an example, here's a link to a section of the administrative laws, which deals with [driving without a license](http://www.prav-net.ru/statya-127-upravlenie-transportnym-sredstvom-voditelem-ne-imeyushhim-prava-upravleniya-transportnym-sredstvom/).  In that section, the wording is:

> Статья 12.7 - **Управление транспортным средством** водителем, не имеющим права **управления транспортным средством**

(highlights are mine - to emphasise the use of the instrumental case).

Comment: Is "управление транспортного средства" incorrect? Why?

Comment: Phrase _управление транспортного средства_ in itself is correct, but not in the context you indicated. Genitive case should be used when describing different parts of a vehicle, e.g. _управление транспортного стредства_, _тормозная система транспортного средства_, _кузов траспортного средства_ etc. - that is when you are describing parts of the vehicle.  When you are talking about a person controlling the vehicle, instrumental case should be used.

Comment: Genitive case would imply that you are dealing with a part of the vehicle rather than controlling the vehicle, e.g. _он пытался отремонтировать автобус, разобрался с тормозами, но не справился с управлением автобуса_.

Comment: обслуживание транспортного средства, ремонт транспортного средства, проверка транспортного средства, наладка транспортного средства, проектировка транспортного средства etc. - In none of these cases the first word denotes a physical part of the vehicle. Rather, it denotes a certain action that takes the vehicle as its object. Why then управление cannot denote such an action?

Comment: 1) ремонт (чего?) дома, самолёта, транспортного средства. 2) управление (чем?) домом, самолётом, транспортным средством. in (1) action points to an object. in (2) human action implies

Comment: Think of a verb version: _управлять (чем) транспортным средством_.  Following from here, _водитель управлял транспортным средством и не справился с управлением транспортным средством_.

Comment: @AleksG - But what if I don't mean a physical part by the word "управлением", but simply mean an kind of action? For example, it is not a physical part that is meant in "Не справился с управлением политбюро" - here a certain action is meant, not a physical part, so why then when I talk about a vehicle, I should by all means mean a physical part of it? What if I simply mean an action of controlling a vehicle, why then I can't use genitive?

Comment: @AleksG - Few more examples, in which the word following "не справился с" implies an action, not a physical part: "не справился с восстанием рабов", "не справился с достижением ожидаемых результатов", "не справился с возникновением угрозы", "не справился с бегством заключённых", "не справился с дежурством", "не справился с партией (ролью) Отелло", "не справился с функцией патрульного". And the words that follow the action words denote something, to which that action is somehow related. For example, the action "достижение" is somehow related to "ожидаемые результаты"

Comment: @eugene - see my replies to AleksG above.

Comment: @brilliant It does not matter a physical object whether or not, animate or not,  in this context the noun "управление" requires the instrumental case. Управление (чем?) государством, велосипедом, коллективом, предприятием, политической партией, оркестром, транспортным средством.
See the difference of paragraphs 1 and 3 - [управление](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F3%EF%F0%E0%E2%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5&all=x)

Comment: @eugene - I've looked through paragraphs 1 and 3 in your link- just as you said - and found in paragraph 3 this example: "Рулевое у. автомобИЛЯ" - that is Genitive, not Instrumental! Therefore, I think both Instrumental and Genitive are correct.

Comment: @brilliant When you say _рулевое управление автомобиля_, you are still referring to a part of the vehicle.  In the original sentence, you have a main object that is controlling something.  In such construct, you should always use instrumental case.  The main point here is an object that is controlling the subject: driver is controlling the vehicle, hence _водитель не справился с управлением транспортным средством_.

Comment: @AleksG - "In the original sentence, you have a main object that is controlling something" - Where is the object in the original sentence? What is it controlling?

Comment: @brilliant You don't get the difference §1 and §3 in [управление](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F3%EF%F0%E0%E2%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5&all=x). §1 — action, management, processing, guide, execution. §3 — thing, device, instrument, hardware, unit. §1 required Instrumental case, §3 required Genitive case.  In the original sentence `водитель` is subject, `транспортное средство` — object, subject managed object.

Comment: @eugene - So, why can I not say that я не справился с a certain device or some hardware? Is it incorrect in Russian, for example, to say "Я не справился с замком" meaning that I have failed to figure out how to open the lock?

Comment: @brilliant Я не справился с замком - absolutely correct, but what does this have to the topic?

Comment: @eugene - "but what does this have to the topic?" - If "Я не справился с замком" is in Russian correct, then to say "Я не справился с управлением" (meaning the car's steering device) should also be all right. If so, then, following the logic of §3, choosing Genitive case here would be the right thing to do, that is, "Не справился с управлением транспортного средства" should be just fine then. No?

Comment: @brilliant `Не справился с управлением транспортного средства` means 'Not figured out how to start the engine', while `Не справился с управлением транспортным средством` means 'low driving skills cause car accident'

Comment: @eugene - I wouldn't say that "Не справился с управлением транспортного средства" means strictly 'Not figured out how to start the engine' (which is "не справился с зажиганием"). This phrase has a way broader meaning and can well mean "Failed to use the steering device in the right way" implying that this failure has consequently lead to a car accident. If so, then Genitive case here is absolutely correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8206/discussion-between-eugene-and-brilliant)

Comment: I think the second example in this answer does not prove the first. In the second example, управление refers to action.

Comment: Everyone: Please stop posting on here and move the discussion over to chat. Comments are not meant for discussions.